# Does ZeroMQ have a notification/callback event/message for when data arrives?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mfc, zeromq

I am trying to integrate ZMQ into an existing windows application that relies heavily on MFC sockets (CASyncSocket).

I've got a CWinThread derived UI thread (without a GUI) that communicates with a server asynchronously using CAsyncSocket.  I would like to add a ZMQ inproc communication line to handle communicating the data received from the server (on a REQ/REP basis) to other threads within the application.

Using CAsyncSocket, the OnReceive method is called by the MFC framework whenever new data is available on the socket to be received (that might be an over-simplification to the hardcore MFC gurus out there).

Is there any such mechanism in ZMQ?  Or do I have to add an additional dedicated WorkerThread that the UI thread launches to handle my ZMQ communications to the rest of the app?  The traffic on both pipelines is minimal so I really don't want to have to create 2 separate threads if I can get by with 1.

Note, I've got the basics working, I'm just having problems with synchronization.  If I use blocking recv/send with ZMQ, it starves out my CAsycSocket because the windows messages never get processed by the thread resulting in sometimes never getting the data from the server that the ZMQ is supposed to be delivering.  But if I use non-blocking ZMQ calls, then the thread frequently ends up sitting idle because it doesn't know to read off the ZMQ socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer is **no**.  There are no current callback/notifications for when data arrives in ZeroMQ that you can link into.  I was also unable to find any fork that adds this functionality.

I was unable to get ZMQ working while using the traditional OnReceive calls provide by the MFC socket framework within a single thread and adding a 2nd thread to dedicate to ZMQ defeated the whole purpose for using it (it is being used for thread synchronization).

My implementation that works ended up dropping MFC sockets and using ZMQ for both my inproc server (for communicating with other thread) as well as my TCP (non-ZMQ) server connection and using a blocking polling call (zmq_poll()) in the OnIdle() method (returning 1 every time to create a busy loop).  The blocking poll

```
BOOL CMyThreaClass::OnIdle(LONG lCount)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lCount);

    zmq_pollitem_t items [] = {
    { m_pZMQInprocServer, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
    { m_pZMQTCPSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };
    const int iZMQInfiniteTimeout(-1);
    iResult = zmq_poll(&items[0], sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]), iZMQInfiniteTimeout);
    TRACE("zmq_poll result: %d\n", iResult);

    if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
    {
        sMyStruct sMessage;
        iResult = zmq_recv(m_pZMQInprocServer, &sMessage, sizeof(sMessage), ZMQ_DONTWAIT); // don't block (the zmq_poll blocks for us)
        TRACE("inproc recv result: %d\n", iResult);
        //  Process inproc messages
        iResult = zmq_send(pZMQInprocServer, &sMessage, sizeof(sMessage), ZMQ_NULL); // block
        TRACE("inproc send result: %d\n", iResult);
    }
    if (items[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
    {
        // there will be an ZMQ_IDENTITY identifier on the beginning of the socket buffer, read it off first
        uint8_t id [256];
        size_t id_size = 256;
        iResult = zmq_getsockopt(m_pZMQTCPSocket, ZMQ_IDENTITY, id, &id_size);
        TRACE("getsockopt poll result %d:id %d\n", iResult, id);
        iResult = zmq_recv(m_pZMQTCPSocket, &id, id_Size, ZMQ_DONTWAIT); // don't block
        // now get our actual data
        char szBuffer[1024];
        int iBytesReceived = zmq_recv(m_pZMQSocket, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
        if (iBytesReceived > 0)
        {
            // process TCP data
        }
    }
}
```

Note:  This answer requires using ZMQ 4 or later since earlier versions of ZMQ will not communicate with a regular TCP socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `zmq_recv()` with the `ZMQ_NOBLOCK` flag inside your app's main message loop by overriding your `CWinApp::OnIdle()`.  `zmq_recv` will return immediately if there is no data waiting on the socket.  If there's data, handle it - but be aware that if you do something slow, you'll make the app unresponsive.

Edit: I didn't realize that `OnIdle` only gets called once when the message queue becomes empty.  But according to [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e077sxt.aspx), you can return a nonzero value to keep getting called forever:

1. If the message loop checks the message queue and finds no pending messages, it calls `OnIdle` and supplies `0` as the `lCount` argument.
2. `OnIdle` performs some processing and returns a nonzero value to indicate it should be called again to do further processing.
3. The message loop checks the message queue again. If no messages are pending, it calls `OnIdle` again, incrementing the `lCount` argument.
4. Eventually, `OnIdle` finishes processing all its idle tasks and returns `0`. This tells the message loop to stop calling `OnIdle` until the next message is received from the message queue, at which point the idle cycle restarts with the argument set to `0`.

I also found [this thread on GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/275216-where-is-message-loop-in-mfc-application/) where a user said:

> All of the tools I have ever written in MFC that use D3D use the OnIdle() function:

```
BOOL CD3DEditorApp::OnIdle(LONG lCount) 
{
    // Call base class first
    CWinApp:OnIdle( lCount );

    // game stuff...

    // Always return true - this asks the framework to constantly
    // call the Idle function when it isn't busy doing something
    // else.
    return TRUE;
}
```

So, at least according to one person, it's a common technique.

Comment: This is actually how I currently have it implemented (using OnIdle within the CWinThread derived class) although I'm just using a zmq_recv instead of a poll since I only have a single communication channel setup right now.  The problem is that I have no way of controlling when OnIdle will be called and what ends up happening is the receiving thread is sitting idle (having already processed an OnIdle event where there was nothing to be read) when the sender sends it a new request.  The new request doesn't trigger another read.

Comment: edited, you can return nonzero from `OnIdle` to ask MFC to call it again.

Comment: The reason this (edited) solution doesn't work for me is because I've got ZMQ in a separate thread from the main app that is usually idle.  always returning true to OnIdle in an Idle thread creates a busy loop and consumes 100% of a CPU core doing nothing.  Returning false results in the thread stopping because ZMQ isn't tied into the message pump in anyway and as a result OnIdle isn't ever called again.

Comment: OK so you've got one "networking" thread that listens to both a `CWinSocket` and ZMQ?  I think this might be difficult.  If you were using raw Winsock sockets you could use `zmq_poll()` because it also accepts raw sockets, but I'm assuming you're in too deep in the MFC world to do that.  I'd probably just spawn a separate thread to poll ZMQ with infinite timeout, and push custom messages to the MFC thread when data arrives.  I know it seems wasteful but OS's can deal with hundreds/thousands of threads, and ZMQ should idle efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

You can signal from thread to thread with custom Windows messages. Here is a custom message:

```
#define WM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_APP + 1)
```

To send it to a thread that has a window use PostMessage or SendMessage to the HWND. Add it to the window's message map with ON_MESSAGE.

To send it to a CWinThread-derived thread that has no windows use PostThreadMessage and receive it with ON_THREAD_MESSAGE.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question asked.  Unless of course you are suggesting to modify ZMQ to post messages to the the parent thread and then create custom event handling similar to MFC sockets.  Also, it is a terrible idea to use SendMessage between threads.  Would down vote if I could.